# special char in a latex equation

Tags: equations

I don't know how to make this special char in latex equation, if anyone could please advise:

[image]

Comment: @PaulGessler but this is not a theta, right?

Comment: It is; but it's a _capital_ theta. You can compare with lower-case $\theta$.

Comment: okay, thank you. Can you post it as an answer to accept it?

Comment: Standard practice for these types of questions is to call this question a duplicate of our catch-all "what symbol is this?" question I linked to above. Your question will stay here, and anyone who searches for this topic will be pointed to the more general question.

Comment: okay, but usually this will be referred to in an answer not a comment right?

Comment: Yes. There's an answer to the question this is a duplicate of...